# Proving socio-economic and financial ties when applying for a UK visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, premium-services

I'm planning to invite my parents to the UK and I'm going to sponsor their entire trip. My father is a self-employed business owner and my mother is a housewife, but to show their socio-economic and financial ties back in India, we are planning to show:

- 6 months business bank account statement of my dad
- 6 months personal savings account statement of my dad
- 3 years of income tax returns
- GST registration certificate
- 3 recent business invoices
- Land deed title (original and translation) owned by my father
- Sale deed of commercial property owned by my mother along with a few partners
- Land valuation (they built their house on it and live there)
- Bonafide certificate from my brother's school (he is not travelling with them)
- Letter from my aunty that she will take care of my brother for the period they will travel
- Aadhar cards of my brother and sisters and a few other family members in India

Are these documents enough to show their ties in India? Should I add anything else to make their case more appealing?

Comment: I believe it would be more relevant to include his personal bank account statements rather than those of the business, as money in the business is not necessarily money that is available to him. Also is there any justification of his actual revenue from the business? This probably depends on the form of the business (don’t know the specifics in India), but there should be some document which establishes how much money goes from the business to his own pocket (then corroborated by the income tax return).

Comment: @jcaron yes, we will include personal account bank statements along with business bank statements. and we can show a balance sheet of the business filled by an accountant, to give a clearer picture but since it's not an official document, I doubt it will hold any value.

Comment: How long are they planning to stay? What’s the nature of your father’s business, will anyone be running it on his behalf while he’s in the UK?